# Show content of other domain inside WordPress

Tags: multisite, domain

I'm very new to WordPress, to any kind of Web-Hosting, actually, so my question might be strange or stupid. I apologize in advance. ;)

I recently started to set up the infrastructure for a small project, I'll be working on. It needs a blog (WordPress) and a project management tool (Redmine) and both should blend in as good as possible - especially domain-wise (I'm also trying to get the themes to be similar but lets see how that works out...). I found a hoster for the domain and Wordpress and another for Redmine.

It is pretty easy to set up Wordpress at *blog.example.com* and create a CNAME Record for *redmine.example.org* which allows the user to feel like staying within the same domain when going from the blog to project management.

But it would be even nicer, if I could create a page in WordPress which shows the content of *redmine.example.org*. Then the user would still see the menu, the feeds and whatever else I setup in Wordpress.

Is that even possible? I googled a lot but found nothing.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: There're dozens of options. iFrame for example. How do you want to achieve that? Keep in mind that plugin recommendations are off topic.

Comment: I had no clue how I wanted to achieve it - hence the question. ;) No, I think that an iFrame is an acceptable solution. What others are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the simplest way to do that would be to put the Redmine content in an `<iframe>`.

While you could (and probably should) create some type of a custom template in your theme for this particular content, there are [plugins that embed iframes into content](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=iframe).

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Apparently too easy for my complicated searches. ;) Thanks, @butlerblog!

PS: I would like to upvote but my reputation doesn't allow me to. :(

Comment: No problem - hope it works out for you.